# TFS 2010 Unable to deploy multiple websites using Web Deploy profile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to implement continues delivery using TFS 2010. Package is created but package is not deployed to Remote Server.
Following things I have done.

---

1. Created "Web Deploy" publish profile for all the websites residing in single solution
2. Installed WMSVC on IIS 7
3. Verified TFS has VS2010 installed

---

Following are my MSBuild Arguments : 
`/p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:PublishProfile=ST.pubxml /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:Password=V******123 /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0`

I tried most of the combinations of build argument but no luck. Not really sure if TFS 2010 supports CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after digging through internet and local help I have successfully enabled **Continues Integration and Continues Deployment**.

**Step 1 :** Install Windows Platform installer + Web Deploy on TFS as well as on Remote/destination Server.

> http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

**Step 2** : Create IIS Manager User Account

**Step 3** : Configure Publish Profiles and Build Definition.

> http://www.johandorper.nl/log/publish-multiple-webprojects-on-build

and use **User** created in Step 2

**step 4 :** Make sure appropriate version is present in TFS server at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio

If absent then copy it from development machine to TFS

**Step 5 :** Allow an IIS Manager user to connect to a site or an application

**Step 6 :** Add "Authenticated Users" to root of the application.

Following are build arguments in build definition

> /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:TransformConfigFiles=true  /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:PublishProfile=ST.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:Username=my-deploy /p:Password=mypassword

You can also specify which configuration (debug/release/test) to use in build definition by creating environment specific web.config

Answer (score 0):

We have deployed from TFS 2010 using MSDeploy.  The only difference I see is we didn't use publish profiles.  Here are the MSBuild arguments we used:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:Configuration=Release 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True  
/p:DeployIisAppPath=staging.example.com   
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://staging.example.com:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

UPDATE -

We no longer deploy directly from MSBuild because we didn't like building every time we want to deploy.  Instead we create an MSDeploy package using MSBuild.  Then we deploy that packages to each environment using MSDeploy.exe.  Here is an overview of WebDeploy that may be helpful -

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

Comment: I agree, but this will not help deploy multiple sites at one go and there you need publish profile.

Comment: Is there a tutorial you're following?  Is there an error?  Can you run with a verbose flag to get all the details?  Can you provide the log?

Comment: There is no error. It just creates package but does not try to deploy on remote server. I have followed below url's. [Configuring multiple websites](http://www.johandorper.nl/log/publish-multiple-webprojects-on-build) [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)

Comment: Used command line "msbuild" utility and was able to deploy it successfully on remote server using following command `msbuild E:\Apps\1.0.0.0\Team.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ST.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:Password=T********3 /p:TransformConfigFiles=true`. But, for me this is not an ideal solution. I will still prefer continues deployment using TFS.

Comment: We use MSDeploy commands within Thoughtworks GO to orchestrate our deployments.  You may evaluate it or other orchestration options.